# Woocommerce checkout/cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not very familiar with woocommerce, and therefore i ask if someone here knows what to do.

I'm creating a website for a travel agent, and they sell trips, i decided to use woocommerce for them but i'm having issues with the checkout.

It's a single trip booking site, so the user selects how many adults, how many children get's a price and can book. But it seems that the trip (Cart Content) is stuck in the cart all the time, so if the user for an example cancels and does the process again, the old booking remains in the cart.

Is there a way around this, so if the user hits back, or doesn't complete the order the cart will not store the other order details or cart content ?.

Comment: Also, FYI to explain this a little better, the site does not have a "Cart", there is just a trip details page (Product Details) and from there they Book (Checkout). That's why i need to cart to clean it self...

Comment: By default, I think WooCommerce cleans the cart every 2 days. I don't know how your user "cancels" but you should be able to get that button to trigger [`WC()->cart->empty_cart()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L293) and that would clean anything out of the cart.